# Change cv2.merge on matplotlib/numpy library command

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, matplotlib

I would like to change my code line "cv2.merge" to command from matplotlib/numpy library.
This is my only line in code from cv2 and I don't know how to get rid of it.

dataStretched have max value 1.0, min 0.0 and size 237614.
With cv2.merge I merge additional arrays which give a color to the image.

The code:

```
data1Color=cv2.merge((dataStretched*0,dataStretched*0,dataStretched*1))
```

Print dataStretched:

```
[[0.09756098 0.14634146 0.02439024 ... 0.17073171 0.41463415 0.2195122 ]
 [0.07317073 0.09756098 0.12195122 ... 0.2195122  0.19512195 0.17073171]
 [0.04878049 0.07317073 0.09756098 ... 0.2195122  0.2195122  0.14634146]
 ...
 [0.19512195 0.04878049 0.19512195 ... 0.29268293 0.2195122  0.26829268]
 [0.3902439  0.17073171 0.09756098 ... 0.2195122  0.12195122 0.07317073]
 [0.17073171 0.14634146 0.17073171 ... 0.14634146 0.17073171 0.09756098]]
```

Print data1Color:

```
[[[0.         0.         0.09756098]
  [0.         0.         0.14634146]
  [0.         0.         0.02439024]
  ...
  [0.         0.         0.17073171]
  [0.         0.         0.41463415]
  [0.         0.         0.2195122 ]]

 [[0.         0.         0.07317073]
  [0.         0.         0.09756098]
  [0.         0.         0.12195122]
  ...
  [0.         0.         0.2195122 ]
  [0.         0.         0.19512195]
  [0.         0.         0.17073171]]

 [[0.         0.         0.04878049]
  [0.         0.         0.07317073]
  [0.         0.         0.09756098]
  ...
  [0.         0.         0.2195122 ]
  [0.         0.         0.2195122 ]
  [0.         0.         0.14634146]]

 ...

 [[0.         0.         0.19512195]
  [0.         0.         0.04878049]
  [0.         0.         0.19512195]
  ...
  [0.         0.         0.29268293]
  [0.         0.         0.2195122 ]
  [0.         0.         0.26829268]]

 [[0.         0.         0.3902439 ]
  [0.         0.         0.17073171]
  [0.         0.         0.09756098]
  ...
  [0.         0.         0.2195122 ]
  [0.         0.         0.12195122]
  [0.         0.         0.07317073]]

 [[0.         0.         0.17073171]
  [0.         0.         0.14634146]
  [0.         0.         0.17073171]
  ...
  [0.         0.         0.14634146]
  [0.         0.         0.17073171]
  [0.         0.         0.09756098]]]
```

Comment: `data1Color = np.stack([dataStretched*0, dataStretched*0, dataStretched*1], axis=2)`

Comment: Great, that answer my question, thank You!